# Can't start any processes, getting permission errors

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-mate

I have a problem.

I was running bash in my terminal and when I executed the `mv` command, I got an error saying `exec: mv: permission denied`. I thought it was like my other permission errors, and so I ran `sudo mv file folder`, which gave me the same error.

I went to google the problem, but Firefox couldn't open, because of permission errors.

Because of all this, I rebooted  (which worked, strangely, so it seems to only affect my user)

But X11 hanged when starting, so I switched to a TTY. (tty2 if that helps) I typed in my username and password, but my shell wouldn't start because of (you've probably guessed by now).

I would log into another user, but I only have the one and root doesn't have a password.

I'm writing this from my phone, but my computer's running Linux 5.8.34-generic Ubuntu MATE 20.10 and my own desktop environment.

## Update:

I've installed Kubuntu now. That makes it the ninth Linux distribution I've installed in six months... I have a separate /home partition and a script for generating scripts that reinstall all my packages.

Comment: Sounds like you did something else. Getting `permission denied` after `mv` should mean that your system hasn't changed. Are you sure you didn't run anything else before the errors started appearing?

Comment: Come to think of it, I was installing [curly](https://curly-lang.org) as root in another terminal...

Comment: Logged in with systemd emergency mode and everything in my bin folder has executable perms (-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root)

Comment: `Jan 05 11:47:18 Laptop su[1769]: pam_systemd(su-1:session): Failed to connect to system bus: No such file or directory`

Comment: Okay, first error message in the logs is `Jan... Laptop systemd[982]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied`

Comment: Y'know, I've been thinking of trying Kubuntu for a while...